# How to add onclick or onmousedown in select tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

as I said I wanted to add onmousedown or onclick in select tag so that when I select an option from select tag, it'll fire up a function which will make visibility to another html tag, like a div tag! I used css to make the div tag's visibility to none!
When the relevant option is clicked, I want to show up that div tag in my page but it doesn't work the way I want!
I think, the code and a screen shot might help you guys to detect what I am not getting right in the code! Please, help me in this regard!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function mouseDown(){
    var element1 = document.getElementById("Nl").value;
    var element2 = document.getElementById("bld").value;
    var element3 = document.getElementById("hspt").value;
    var changing = document.getElementById("Hp");
    var changingV2 = document.getElementById("BB");

    if(element3 == "Hospitals"){
        changing.style.display = "block";
        changingV2.style.display = "none";  
    }
    if(element2 == "bloodBanks"){
        changing.style.display = "none";
        changingV2.style.display = "block";
    }
    /*else
    document.write("nothing should happen!");*/
}
</script>
<select id = "cate">
    <option id = "Nl" value = "" onclick = "ClickToChange()"></option>
    <option id = "hspt" value = "Hospitals" onclick = "ClickToChange()">Hospital</option>
    <option id = "bld" value = "bloodBanks" onclick = "ClickToChange()">Blood Bank</option>

</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id = "Hp" style = "display:none">
    <div>Hospital</div>
    <input id = "hosital" type = "text" maxlength = "40">
</div>
<div id = "BB" style = "display:none">
    <div>Blood Banks</div>
    <input id = "bloodbank" type = "text" maxlength = "40">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was a well-asked question. You have done a good job describing your desired result, as well as posting concise code. Hopefully the answer now linked to your question will provide the solution you’re looking for. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @JamesHill thanks for showing me the right question and I got my answer! :D and should i delete as it seemed duplicate of another question?

Comment: No need to delete. All is well :-)